# Laravel4 pagination is stuck

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-pagination

I have a quite-complex query with lots of joins and wheres via Eloquent instance which starts with

```
$user = new User;
$query =User::join('table','users.id','=','table.id');
```

After that i'm looping and adding lots of ->whereRaw() entries.

In the end of it, im running:

```
return $query->paginate(30);
```

on the view itself i'm running

```
{{ $records->appends($_GET)->links() }}
```

Everything looks OK but the thing is that after the first page (when I paginate to page #2) the paginator links are stuck on 2 and doesnt go on.

Probably a CodeIgniter thinking tried on Laravel.. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the page number to `appends` (as you're passing the whole of $_GET) which is why it gets stuck. Either be more specific with your `appends` call or use `Input::except('page')` or similar.